# Can anybody define the meaning of the word "Inspiron"?

Tags: synonyms

As you are familiar with the Dell inspiron laptops, I was wondering what does it actually mean , its origin..

Comment: It means that the marketing guys succeeded in getting your attention. That's what *fanciful terms* (made up trademarks) are all about.

Comment: Please include your research in your questions.

Comment: It's a proper name. As such, it doesn't really *mean* anything. (And it wouldn't matter if it did. But it doesn't.) It is a label for a thing.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking about the origin and meaning of a trade name, and not common English.

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be

> Inspire + Celeron = Inspiron

[From Wikipedia:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dell_Inspiron#Inspiron_530)

> Released on June 26, 2006, the Dell Inspiron 530 is Dell's first desktop to use the Inspiron name. The Inspiron 530 has an Intel Celeron 450

Comment: Please provide the Wikipedia link.

Answer (score 0):

The root definitely hints that these models are connected with "inspiration" - a marketing move. It could be that it also sounds similar to Celeron (as Celeron processors were used in first models alongside with Pentium II as mplungjan mentioned), though I couldn't find any mention of this fact.

Comment: In the wikipedia article.

Comment: I just checked it and did not see any explicit statement on the fact the name "Inspiron" was based on Celeron processor name, even though it is a pretty valid and probable guess since Celeron name was widely used at the time, and that made "Inspiron" sound more recognizable.

Comment: But Celeron must have something to do with celery, doesn't it?

Comment: "Celeron" is probably a play on "celerity"—"rapidity of motion or action." The "-on" suffix shows up in product names to enhance their seeming scientificness—for example, in Orlon (synthetic fiber), Techron (magic ingredient in Chevron gasoline), Calgon (water softener), Darvon (prescription drug), and Acrylon (plastics maker).